# Rename particular set of files (Linux)

Tags: linux

I have the following files:

```
boxScoreBaseball.html.php
boxScoreBasketball.html.php
boxScoreBowling.html.php
boxScoreCheer.html.php
boxScoreCrew.html.php
boxScoreCrossCountry.html.php
boxScoreEquestrian.html.php
boxScoreFieldHockey.html.php
boxScoreFootball.html.php
boxScoreGolf.html.php
boxScoreGymnastics.html.php
boxScoreHockey.html.php
boxScoreLacrosse.html.php
boxScoreRugby.html.php
boxScoreSkiing.html.php
boxScoreSoccer.html.php
boxScoreSoftball.html.php
boxScoreSwimming.html.php
boxScoreTennis.html.php
boxScoreTrack.html.php
boxScoreVolleyball.html.php
boxScoreWaterPolo.html.php
boxScoreWrestling.html.php
```

I would like to take the `boxScore` portion off of each file, so, for example, `boxScoreBaseball.html.php` would become `baseball.html.php`. What the easiest way to do this?

Comment: See [rename](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_rename.htm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably only works with Bash:

`for i in boxScore*; do mv $i ${i#boxScore}; done`

I always use this reference for quick-and-dirty bash stuff: http://aurelio.net/shell/canivete/en/ (see section 4).

Comment: There's nothing particularly Basish here. Take care to use double quotes around file names, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly rename all, you must use a bash script.
Maybe these links will be usefull for you:

- [Renaming multiple files at a shell prompt](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/renaming-multiple-files-at-a-shell-prompt.html)
- [Rename files using a regex with bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961255/)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `mmv` (See [this article for more examples](http://linux.dsplabs.com.au/mmv-copy-append-link-move-multiple-files-under-linux-shell-bash-by-wildcard-patterns-p5/)).

For the given example:

```
mmv "boxScore*.html.php" "#1.html.php"
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this little shell script:

```
for file in *; do echo "${file:8}" | sed -e 's/^\([A-Z]\)\(.*\)/\l\1\2/' | xargs mv "$file"; done
```

We iterate through every file in the current directory. First, we echo the file name without the first 8 characters. Then we use `sed` to convert the first character to lower case. The `sed` search expression means "beginning of line, group 1: an uppercase letter, group 2: the rest", and the replacement expression means "lowercase matching group 1, and then append group 2". The last part just moves the old file to the transformed file name.